# How to pass dependency in useEffect hook inside Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an `useEffect` hook inside Context. Also, i have two functional component, from one of them, i am calling context like `const context = useContext(ApiContext);` but at the same time, from the same component, need to pass dependency of `useEffect` as well so that `useEffect` code should execute only if the dependency changes, here for example.."Name" and "Range". Below is my context code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const ApiContext = React.createContext();

const Context = props => {
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('rendered');
    setArticles(['Article One', 'Article Two', '...ect']);
  }, [props.Name, props.Range]);

  return <ApiContext.Provider value={articles}>{props.children}</ApiContext.Provider>;
};

export default Context;
```

Here is codeSandBox exmaple: https://codesandbox.io/s/route-rerender-api-fix-q9tu2

How to passs `props.Name` and `props.Range` from from my functional component?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use case? I suppose you could initialize another state and populate it with the props coming in but it smells like a bad architectural decision/choice...

Comment: What do you want to achieve at the end?

Comment: @felixmosh I want to make `useEffect` code run only if `[props.Name, props.Range]` changes. How to do it?

Comment: @SakoBu I want to make useEffect code run only if [props.Name, props.Range] changes. How to do it

Comment: @Lara, I've asked the end goal, not how to fix your implementation, cause I think that the approach that you took is not the "hooks" way

Comment: @felixmosh Apologies. allow me to elaborate, I have some routes which calls API to display data on pageLoad. I want to call API only once and keep the data if there is just Route Change and if there are some page level dependencies changes like `Name` and `Range` then only `useEffect` hook to fetch the API data should get called..

Comment: @SakoBu Here is what i want to achieve..I have some routes which calls API to display data on pageLoad. I want to call API only once and keep the data if there is just Route Change and if there are some page level dependencies changes like Name and Range then only useEffect hook to fetch the API data should get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this to spread all the props from parent - class component

```
<Context {...this.props} >....your components...</Context>,
```

or like for specific

```
   <Context name='test'>... your components ....</Context>
```

and you can access like in the context

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("rendered with props", props.name);
    setArticles(['Article One', 'Article Two', '...ect']);
  }, [props.name]);
```

working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59371292-so-rkd2v) - check the console

passing input from child component - [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59371292-so-tkx72)

Comment: How is `onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}` calling `useEffect`. I need `useEffect` to be executed only if the Name value changed. Can you please explain your solution a little more. Thanks

Comment: sure for example i will add a input field and make it working give me some minute

Comment: you can check the same codesandbox so once you type in the console the context will be called check it and let me know

Comment: Thanks. Just a query, What if i want to call it from `First.js` instead `index.js`? How to do that?

Comment: using callback function, updated with another codesandbox let me know if you got a clear on this

Comment: Yes, Thanks a ton!